# Some help needed with translation of fol sentences

Tags: first-order-logic

Let the predicate letters *M* (unary) and *E* (binary) respectively stand for "Is a mouse" and "Eats"

1: $\neg \exists z (Mz \wedge Ezz)$

There is no mouse that eats itself

2: $\forall x(Mx \rightarrow \forall y(My \rightarrow \neg Exy))$

Mice do not eat each other

3: $\forall x (Mx \rightarrow \forall y (Exy \rightarrow My))$

This one has me stumped! For all mice that gets eaten, it is done by other mice? If x is a mouse, if it gets eaten by something, then that other something is a mouse? If a mouse gets eaten by all things that eat, its a mouse?

---

Let the unary predicate letters $V,K, L$ respectively stand for "is vegetarian", "is cheese", and "is meat" and the binary predicate letter $E$ stand for "eat".

1: There is a vegetarian that doesn't eat cheese

$\exists x (Vx \wedge \forall y (Ky \rightarrow \neg Exy))$

But can I also say:

$\forall x (Kx \rightarrow \exists y (Vy \wedge \neg Eyx))$?

2: Who doesn't eat meat, is a vegetarian

Again, this one has me stumped. I would write it like this:

$\forall x \forall y ((Ly \wedge \neg E(x, y)) \rightarrow Vx)$

Comment: (3) says that mice eat only other mice. (2) is missing a 'y'.

Comment: In the second half, in (2), you should write 'L' for 'M'. The rest looks fine.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan You're absolutely right! I've edited my post. If you had this as an answer, I could upvote you :-)

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Also, do you see that ∀x(Kx→∃y(Vx∧¬Exy)) isn't the same as ∃x(Vx∧∀y(Ky→¬Exy))? Imagine an empty world. In that world, the first formula is vacuously true, while since there is no vegetarian in that world, the second it false.

Comment: Oh wow, you upped the ante. No, I did not consider this. But now the question is which one fits better? I would say the first one, since it explicitly says "There IS a vegetarian".

Comment: That does sound better. Also, there is a typo in the second alternative in (1) of the second half: instead of 'Vx' you probably meant 'Vy'. Now, after fixing the typo, it says: every cheese is s.t. there is some vegetarian s.t. he/she isn't eaten by that cheese. Certainly not what you wanted to say.

Comment: Right, because it said that if there is a cheese it is a vegetarian. That's indeed not what I wanted to say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first half looks good, and (3) says that mice eat only other mice. As regards the second half, I'd offer the following formulas (close to what you have, except the one I mentioned in the comments).

> 1: There is a vegetarian that doesn't eat cheese:

$\exists x(Vx ~\land \forall y(Exy \rightarrow \lnot Ky)$ ("someone is a vegetarian s.t. everything he/she eats isn't cheese").

> 2: Who doesn't eat meat, is a vegetarian:

$\forall x: Vx \lor \exists y(Ly \land Exy)$ ("everyone is either a vegetarian or there is a meat he/she eats").

Comment: I'm curious, why at 1 did you choose that over mine? I mean, what does yours say differently than mine?

Comment: I copied your english sentence, and immediately wrote the formula. Then I saw yours and said "oh, one of us is wrong perhaps", but no, they are contrapositives!, your $Ky→¬Exy$ and my Exy→¬Ky that is, so I decided to leave it as it is.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Np. Good luck with everything else.